# NullReferenceException happening randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm currently working on a web application written in ASP.NET using c#.

I have an `OleDBDatareader` reading a webpage content stored in a `.mdb` file and at the same time, another reader seeking the dynamic menu content (same `.mdb` file).

When navigating through pages I randomly get a `NullReferenceEexception` stating that reader is null. This seems to happen on a random page, and on one of the methods using the readers (not always the same one).

Here is the menu code: http://pastebin.com/TCtj3vxj

And here's the page code: http://pastebin.com/gYDHkTKv

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: There is a live version of the exception @ win.abbraccio-onlus.it

Edit 2: Here's the db.EseguiReader code:

```
public OleDbDataReader EseguiReader(string _query)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = this.getConnessione();

                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = _query;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
       }
```

Edit 3: And the stack trace:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   WebApplication3.classi.MenuuService.caricaFigli(String categoria) +322
   WebApplication3.Site1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +192
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: ms-access and concurrence are not good frien.

Comment: Just one suggestion: use aggressive caching and avoid hitting the DB as much as possible. True in general, but much more so with MS Access... BTW, if you're using Access your DB should be less than 2GB in size (if I'm not mistaken on Access' size limits), so it could probably fit completely in memory in your webserver

Comment: You appear to be using some other class to open the DBReader (called database). It's likely the exception is occurring in that class, resulting in it returning a null value. Do you have the source for that class?

Comment: Can you post code for `db.EseguiReader()` method? Specifically how it creates and opens a connection and how it creates the reader.

Comment: Is really the reader null or rather the content of some columns you read via reader["column"]? You simply call ToString on the column values without checking if they are null.

Comment: What line is the exception happening on? Show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `EseguiReader` function. You create a connection as a private variable. When you exit the function - that variable goes out of scope. Eventually Garbage Collector collects it and that closes and disposes your connection, leaving Reader orphaned. This happens randomly because it's unpredictable when GC kicks in.

One solution is to create connection outside of the function and pass it in as one of the parameters, so it won't go out of scope. E.g.

```
public OleDbDataReader EseguiReader(string _query, OleDbConnection conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = _query;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

And call it

```
OleDbConnection conn = this.getConnessione();
OleDbDataReader reader = db.EseguiReader(querypagina, conn);
```

Don't forget to close your reader/connection after the use

[Reference](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/08/30/solution-for-sqldatareader-readcolumnheader-nullreferenceexception/)